# How to use asynchronous JQuery confirm dialog as synchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, callback, jquery-ui-dialog, confirm

I use a simple JavaScript confirm function that is used by all pages in my Asp.net project and I want to **replace it with jQuery confirm dialog**.
I use Apprise jQuery confirm dialog library.
But the asynchronous work of jQuery confirm dialog causes problem.
Let me give you some code examples of my project..

**This is my old JavaScript confirm function**

```
function confirmForOperation(message) {
    if (confirm(message) == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

**This is my new asynchronous jQuery confirm dialog function**

```
function confirmForOperation(message) {
    apprise(message, { 'verify': true, 'animate': true, 'textYes': 'Yes', 'textNo': 'No' },
    function (r) {
        if (r) {
            // User clicked YES..
            return true;
        }
        else {
            // User clicked NO..
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

**You may offer me to use the below function as**

```
function confirmForOperation(message, callBack) {
    apprise(message, { 'verify': true, 'animate': true, 'textYes': 'Yes', 'textNo': 'No' },
    function (r) {
        if (r) {
            // User clicked YES..

            if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                callback.apply();
            }
        }
        else {
            // User clicked NO..
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

But callBack mechanism does not work for me because one of the area(code) I use this confirm dialog function is as below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Delete"
Text="<%$ Resources:BTNResource, BUTTON_DELETE_LABEL %>" OnClientClick="return confirmForOperation();" />
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking this up too, the answer is no. See this excellent explanation here:

[Change the asynchronous jQuery Dialog to be synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962301/change-the-asynchronous-jquery-dialog-to-be-synchronous)